# How to get all instantiated types of a assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime

How i can get all instantiated types of an assembly when it running  ?
I used reflexion but it can retrieve all types but not just instantiated types.

Example:
After Runing the assembly.exe
I want to get

```
System.Object   10 Instances
System.String   102 Instances
System.Char []  10 Instances ....
```

Comment: So any one have an idea on how to do it :) ?